# What does "a process have superuser privileges" mean?

Tags: process, root

From APUE

> 1. If the process has superuser privileges, the setuid function sets the real user ID, effective user ID, and saved set-user-ID to uid.
> 2. If the process does not have superuser privileges, but uid equals either the real user ID or the saved set-user-ID, setuid sets only the
>      effective user ID to uid. The real user ID and the saved set-user-ID
>      are not changed.
> 3. If neither  of  these  two  conditions  is  true, errno is  set  to EPERM and −1 is returned.

What does "a process have superuser privileges" mean?

Does it mean  the  real user of the process have ID 0 i.e. being root?

Does it mean  the  effective user of the process have ID 0 i.e. being root?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In POSIX, a process has superuser privileges if its *effective* user id is 0.

(Some Unix-style systems have different mechanisms; for example, on Linux, the default access-control system also considers capabilities, and you can create a setuid binary which will run with a root effective user but have no capabilities and hence be powerless. See [the `setuid` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html).)

*APUE* is describing the specified behaviour of [`setuid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html). The context is given in the way user ids are set up by [`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html): if an executable has the `setuid` bit set, and its file system is mounted without disabling `setuid`, running it with `exec` results in a process whose effective user is the owner of the file, and whose real and saved user is the calling user.

If `setuid` is called with an effective root user, it replaces all the user ids; otherwise it only replaces the effective id. This ends up being confusing... The reason for this behaviour is given in the rationale of the POSIX spec: `login` and `su` need to be able to change user ids in an irrevocable fashion, and the only way to do that is to replace all the ids.